# How to change the row colour on click in kendo grid

Tags: events, kendo-ui, row, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid which is populating all the records correctly.When I select a particular row I want to change the  colour of that particular row.I am able to select only one row and colour is changing for that.When I click on second row thing doesn't work.I am not able to select the second row and first row remain selected.I am not able to deselect the first row also.Any help will be appreciated.

here is OnChange Event:

```
    var grid = $("#GridTruck").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    $("#GridTruck").selectedItem.Class("color", "green");
   Please help me where I am going wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Multi Row selection on the Grid.

```
.Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple).Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
```

You are only adding the color when selecting but are failing to remove the color when it is de-selected. Instead alter the `k-state-selected` css class and you will not have to manipulate it manually.

```
.k-grid .k-state-selected {
        color: green;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks C Sharper for your valuable suggestion and time.But after adding your code I am facing the same issue again.The On change event fires only once.I am not able to deselect the row..

Comment: Did you remove your code? I believe the problem is here `$("#GridTruck").selectedItem.Class("color", "green");`